# How To Make a "Enter" key by C# in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I wrote this code in C#:

```
using (StreamWriter streamWriter = File.CreateText(@"C:\File.Html"))
{
    streamWriter.WriteLine(TextBox2.Text);
}
```

This code opens File.Html and copies the value of TextBox2 But When I open File.Html all characters are on one line, even though there were multple lines of text in the TextBox.
How do I get the newline characters to show up in the file?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
streamWriter.WriteLine(TextBox2.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>"));
```

Comment: nice . what is the Class of Enviroment ? system. ?

Comment: Sorry, type mismatch. its Environment. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

New lines in HTML are ignored by default. This is why you are not seeing the results you expect to. In order to insert a newline, you need to replace `\n`, which stands for newline, with `<br />`, which is the line break equivalent in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Or you wrap the output in *pre* ("preformatted") tags:

```
streamWriter.WriteLine("<pre>" + TextBox2.Text + "</pre>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use File.WriteAllText instead, avoid having to create new object and dispose it.

You do need to replace new lines with `<br />` as suggested above.